# unable to process the URL in eclips juno

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {background-image:url("../images/liza.jpg");}      //---- this line

</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body >
...
...
...
```

in this code i dont know why i am unable to include this image in my jsp page ....

this is a jsp page designed in eclips juno

the directory structure is

    --> myweblib

      -->---- webcontent

        -->--------- images

          --> --------------liza.jpg

    -->build

url while running this page in eclips

```
http://localhost:8081/MyWebLibrary/books.jsp
```

my jsp file is directly in side the webcontent folder ie: "webcontent/books.jpg" and my image is inside: "webcontent/images/liza.jpg"

Comment: And what's the URL displayed in the browser adress bar when this JSP is executed? Why don't you use absolute URLs rather than relative ones? And why do you have CSS in JSP files and not in CSS files?

Comment: @JBNizet it is :  http://localhost:8081/MyWebLibrary/books.jsp

Comment: So the JSP is in the same directory as images. So you don't need `../`

Comment: one question where have you  kept the jsp page in the directory structure?

Comment: @rahulmaindargi my jsp file is directly in side the webcontent folder ie: "webcontent/books.jpg"  and my image is inside: "webcontent/images/liza.jpg"

Comment: @Mayur have you tried doing ./images...  or just images/... (no leading slash)

Comment: @HugoDozois thnxx .... but i have tried even that combination also... :(

Comment: you have style included in JSP right? not using any .CSS file right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "

css dont need them

Comment: ok got the answer... the file should be in the root directory

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ../ your images are deployed on context, not on host-root

Regards